# what is the meaning of the statement contactList = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 private ListView lv;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  contactList = new ArrayList<>();
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

  new GetContacts().execute();
}
```

what is  the meaning of  the  statement

```
contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

someone please explain

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial site or a programming school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
contactList = new ArrayList<>();
```

will initialize `contactList` with `ArrayList` Object

Answer (score 1):

The line `contactList = new ArrayList<>();` will initialize a new ArrayList object with the name `contactList`.

This means a block of memory will be allocated to store the contents of this list once it is populated with elements. `contactList` now points to this block of memory.

In order to add to, remove from, and manipulate `contactList` in the rest of the body of `MainActivity`, your code needs this line so it knows where in memory to makes these changes.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is a java class which is a list of java objects
ArrayList is like an array but it's size is not fixed and it provide much better function than a normal array..

you can tell ArrayList to store objects of which class like this.

```
contactList = new ArrayList<here_goes_some_class_name>();
```